A lot of sock puppet accounts on the Bitcoin Stack Exchange site
I am aware the the Bitcoin site has its own Meta, but that meta was last active on the 6th of January so am posting here also.
I'm more of a lurker on Bitcoin Stack Exchange than an actual user, but I was lurking (like I do) and I spotted these guys:

dalower
mony
jeme
musakhan
joli
moly
foysal

Update (15th of January), and these guys also, who have hit the Hot Network Questions list again with this:

kayer
jesy
luna
lina

If I was a betting man, I would wager that these are all the same person, just thought I would bring it to your attention!

@TimeTravelingBobby Sure, it's just they seem to have hit the hot network questions list today twice, with basically just spam!

I've already flagged one of the posts.

@Yannis This is something that needs to be dealt with ASAP, last time this happened there was a lot of cleanup involved. Bitcoin is pretty sleepy meta-wise and moderation-wise.

@Yannis Apologies, deleted the question on Meta Bitcoin.

@Yannis Hmm, true.

Is this really related to hot questions? @gnat

Am I the only one that finds sock puppets on a bitcoin site highly ironic?

@MichaelT Phew, sock puppets scare me!

I've cleaned most of this up. There were a lot more accounts... A few still remain, either because they hadn't done anything yet, or had done something potentially useful. 
Thanks for the heads-up. If nothing else, this provided a good opportunity to identify some  deficiencies in my analysis tools. Also another good illustration of how conscientious members of a site can help to identify problems. Kudos, all.

Awesome, I'm happy I was able to contribute, if I spot any more I will update this post, cheers!

Thanks for taking care of that.

Two more for you: one, two.

This has happened before, with a ring of users causing questions to hit the multicollider, reaching 200 rep, and then abusing the network bonus.
I suggest everyone flag the answers as spam.  Not sure if this is the right course of action, but this is best stopped before they reach 200 rep.
I've already pinged a community team member.

every answer? As in, not an "other" flag explaining the situation to  a (hypothetical) mod, like I've  done ~22 hours ago with a flag that's still active? OK...

@JanDvorak Every answer that's just a link. It's pretty obvious that this is a sock ring here.

The Bitcoin mods are less active, a custom flag may not reach in time

@JanDvorak I'm not sure of this though, it does seem like abuse of spam flags.

I've just flagged an answer, then realised that this guy's two questions were perfectly normal. I'm wondering if this was a correct flag.

@JanDvorak I'm talking about the link answers by the flower-gravatar users, not the questions

so, I shouldn't flag the questions? But I use them to find other spam answers

@JanDvorak No. Scratch that, don't flag anything as spam, I'm really unsure of that now

I've tried to crawl the site and I really don't know which of the (link mostly) answers I've found are legitimate. I've flagged cca only two posts so far. I give up.

@JanDvorak Oh, this doesn't look like a long term thing, I think the socking started today.

@ShadowWizard I guess it's tricky because they ask ~passable questions, and then get good answers from other legitimate users, they're annoying me though hence the update!

@ShadowWizard Totally agree with that!
